# Using clip tool (ArcGIS) for iteration/looping 2 GDBs in : one for clipped data, second - for clipping features

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder, clip, loop

I have 2 GDBs. The first one (let's name it X.gdb) contains feature classes (A,B,C...n) that are to be clipped. The second gdb (Y.gdb) contains fc (let's name it border1, border2, border3...) with only one polygonal feature (municipal district) in each. These are clipping features. What I need to do is to create model/python script, that creates separate gdb for every clipping feature (border1.gdb, border2.gdb, border3.gdb...) with clipped features from X.gdb

---

[image]

What kind of mistake did I make?

Comment: I think I have something that does this but can you provide some kind of effort in putting together a script (even if it's pseudo code) to get things started?

Comment: I'm not good in python, but I guess there might be something like this:

Comment: import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "D:\data\X.gdb"
outws = "D:\data”

 clip_features = "D:\data\Y.gdb"
  fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

i=0
for fc in fcs:
    out_feature_class = "D:\data\border.gdb" + str(i)
    i+=1

arcpy.Clip_analysis(fc, clip_features, out_feature_class)

Comment: Okay. Does Y.gdb only have one featurclass representing one municipal district, or are there multiple featureclasses representing various municipal districts?

Comment: there are several feature classes in Y.gdb. Each FC contains one polygon representing sertain municipal district.

Comment: can you marge these files into one feature class so that each line in the merged output has the name of the municipal district and export it to X.gdb?

Comment: Actually, leave the merged file in Y.gdb

Comment: You mean to merge all municipal districts in Y.gdb into a single feature class? And save this fc in X.gdb where all target (clipped) layers are?

Comment: Don't store the merged file in the same one as your other features or it will try to clip itself.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to provide any requested clarifications. That way you will be able to use the format button to prettify your code.

Comment: @Vadim please [edit] your question to include the script you tried and the errors as text rather than as an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge your municipal polygon features into a single file. Make sure there is a name field in your merged out put to specify the polygon representing it's respective municipal district. This code should do the trick once you replace the proper parameters and file locations:

```
import arcpy
import os

outputFolder = r"D:/test"
arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:/test/data_3857.gdb"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#create clip tool parameters
ClipFeatures = r"D:/test/Y.gdb/borders"
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

# use a search cursor to cycle through each municipal district in your merged file, make sure there is a field representing municipal district name, I'm using "Municipality_name" here
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(ClipFeatures, ["SHAPE@", "NAME"]) as rows:
    for row in rows:
        # create fgdb in outputFolder variable, this will create a folder with   the Municipal district name and a file gdb named muni_features.gdb to store the clipped features 
        outGDB = os.path.join("MD_" + row[1], "Muni_features.gdb")
        arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(outputFolder,outGDB)
        print "created", outGDB
        geom = row[0]
        #now clip out each feature in
        for fc in fcs:
            out_feature_class=os.path.join(outputFolder, outGDB,"MD_" + row[1] +  os.path.basename(fc))
            print out_feature_class
            arcpy.Clip_analysis(fc,geom,out_feature_class)
        del row
```

Comment: I try to run the script several times, but couldn't make it work. Is there any mistake&

Comment: @Vadim I have added your error messages from you answer as an edit to your question

Comment: @ShaunO This is my last attempt to run the code. I've got "Parsing error IndentationError: unexpected indent (line 15)" error message. Here is the code:

Comment: @Midavalo Actually I failed to paste the code in a readable format.

Answer (score 0):

Your indentaion is still off. Copy this code. Paste it into a text file. Name it MyClip.py. In the python window in ArcMap, right click in the interactive window. Choose load. Upload MyClip.py. Press enter. Let the code run.[image]

```
import arcpy
import os

outputFolder = r"D:/test"
arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:/test/data_3857.gdb"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#create clip tool parameters
ClipFeatures = r"D:/test/Y.gdb/borders"
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

# use a search cursor to cycle through each municipal district in your merged file, make sure there is a field representing municipal district name, I'm using "Municipality_name" here
with da.SearchCursor(ClipFeatures, ["SHAPE@", "NAME"]) as rows:
    for row in rows:
        # create fgdb in outputFolder variable, this will create a folder with   the Municipal district name and a file gdb named muni_features.gdb to store the clipped features 
        outGDB = os.path.join(outputFolder, row[1], "Muni_features.gdb")
        print "created ", outGDB
        geom = row[0]
        #now clip out each feature in
        for fc in fcs:
            out_feature_class=os.path.join(outGDB,row[1] +  os.path.basename(fc))
            arcpy.Clip_analysis(fc,geom,out_feature_class)
            del fc
        del row
```

Comment: I did as you said. After loading the code i pressed "Enter" but it just put  the cursor down and nothing happend. Than I press "Enter" again and further mistaked appeared: SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print' (<string>, line 17) Please, see the picture: http://i91.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0106/ab/a27a9eced58c8c046e134a10c50629ab.png

Comment: Are you using python 3x? If so then you need parentheses around the print statement. If you load in the arcmap python window I don't think this should be a problem. The IDE in the picture you provided does not appear the python window in ArcMap. As far as I know, ArcMap desktop uses python 2.7 so if you load it in this environment you should't have this issue. I will edit my most recent answer with a pic.

Comment: additionally you can remove the print statement but be careful not to alter the indentation

Comment: Last time I used ArcGIS Pro (run on python 3.4). Now I tried to paste in ArcMap python window. I pressed Enter twice (it was too long to wait and I wasn't sure this code is actually running). And i got this mistake: "Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
NameError: name 'env' is not defined"                                                       The pic is here: http://i91.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0106/54/a1dbc3ee9860d27395dafd7c718ccc54.png

Comment: Almost there. I modified the code to get rid of some module imports specific to my tasks. Added arcpy in front of env as I was importing this specifically from the arcpy library in my earlier version. Should work now.

Comment: Shaun, now it seems the code is ok despite a new mistake appeared. + I added "arcpy." to "da.SearchCursor". But at least it started to work. Look at the pic. I think the problem is in cyrilic symbols and spaces in districts' names:                                                                              http://i91.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0106/16/33194f381f30fe97d3cd5ac193294c16.png

Comment: I created new field in clipping features (not cyrillic: R1 to R43; 1,2,3...43 - sequential number of that municipalities) and changed the code respectively. But that error still appears: Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 22, in <module>   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\analysis.py", line 56, in Clip     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output D:/test\R1\Muni_features.gdb\R1boundary_polygon Failed to execute (Clip).  
screen: http://i90.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0106/66/bee0b3fa8fe3fa52fa2a2146d7550266.png

Comment: yes. Again. I imported those methods straight from the module in my previous script. Let me review and modify.

Comment: Ok. It's because it's trying to name the output beginning with a number. This is not allowed. Modify this line like so out_feature_class=os.path.join(outGDB,"MD_" + row[1] +  os.path.basename(fc))

Comment: Unfortunately, after altering the script as you offered, the error didn't dissapeared. The pic: http://i90.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0107/1d/0142d2c37ffeefebc95d75d82e31ed1d.png

Comment: Need to do it here too: outGDB = os.path.join(outputFolder, "MD_" + row[1], "Muni_features.gdb")  Can't have file gdbs or feature classes starting with numbers.

Comment: It's as pitty: the code still isn't ok(( Maybe there is something wrong with my data? The pic: http://i91.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0107/0f/965d616678a0c2e0dc0406e88dbc2d0f.png

Comment: Modified it once again to include a print statement. This will allow us to see what it's trying to save the file name to. Can you run it again with the new modified code and see what it prints?

Comment: Sorry. I can't modify the original post right now. If you can, add "print out_feature_class" without the quotes after "out_feature_class=os.path.join(outGDB,"MD_" + row[1] +  os.path.basename(fc))". It should be the same indentation as that line. The code will still fail but now maybe we can see why.

Comment: Was finally able to edit original post. Tested code with my own variable names and it worked. Added arcpy.CreateFileGDB_managment(). You should be able to paste the code in my edited original answer and it should work. The absence of the arcpy.CreateFileGDB_managment() was preventing the creation of the output.

Comment: Great Job, Shaun!!! It works! I'm sure your script will be very usefull for many gis users. We should add it to 'favourites').                                http://i91.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0110/37/0e52426057602049eb001ea00a873b37.png

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you (finally). Can you click the check mark next to my original answer so other people know it was accepted?

Answer (score -1):

```
    >>> #Creates clips features based on the selected features from a polygon featureclass and exports the clipped features to a specified GDB
... 
... import arcpy
... import os
... 
... outputFolder = r"D:/test"
... env.workspace = r"D:/test/data_3857.gdb"
... env.overwriteOutput = True
... 
... #create clip tool parameters
... ClipFeatures = r"D:/test/Y.gdb/borders"
... fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
... 
... #use a search cursor to cycle through each municipal district in your     merged file, make sure there is a field representing municipal district name,   I'm using "Municipality_name" here
... with da.SearchCursor(ClipFeatures, ["SHAPE@", "NAME"]) as rows:
... for row in rows:
... # create fgdb in outputFolder variable, this will create a folder with   the Municipal district name and a file gdb named muni_features.gdb to store the   clipped features 
... outGDB = os.path.join(outputFolder, row[1], "Muni_features.gdb")
... print "created ", outGDB
... geom = row[0]
... #now clip out each feature in
... for fc in fcs:
... out_feature_class=os.path.join(outGDB,row[1] +  os.path.basename(fc))
... arcpy.Clip_analysis(fc,geom,out_feature_class)
... del fc
... del row
... 
Parsing error IndentationError: expected an indented block (line 16)
>>>
```

Comment: @ShaunO The above code still doesn't work. The mistake is "Parsing error IndentationError: expected an indented block (line 16)". What it could mean?

Comment: Did you see my comment above?

Comment: You mean this: sorry, everything from the line introducing the search cursor was accidentally indented. Also, are you importing into ArcMap python window from a text file or are you copying and pasting into the window? – ShaunO 18 hours ago
     
@ Vadim I edited my original code to not have the indent. – ShaunO 18 hours ago
     
Try moving everything from "with.da.SearchCursor...." over to the left four spaces or one back indent. – ShaunO 18 hours ago

Comment: @ShaunO I pasted the code into python window in arcmap. Also I pasted it in arcgis pro python window. But failed to get it work in both cases. http://i91.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0106/b0/c7ae2cae9d0e8b497416ad387aed11b0.png                                                                                                       http://i89.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0106/45/81769ad0c6ae4994f3b89d9aa7bd5945.png